# How to make rows invisible while printing reports?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, printing, reportviewer

I am using an .rldc file to define the layout of the reports from my program. The problem is, it is to be used for incremental printing. That means the paper will be used over and over as newer rows need to be printed. I'm attempting to approach it this way:

1. List all corresponding data on the report view.
2. Make the older rows invisible and only show the latest row.
3. Print.

That way, the last row is already properly placed. The problem is, I don't know how to implement this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: How do you assign your DataSource to your report? I had a similar problem. I create DataSets and fill the datatables programmatically. Since it's done in a loop, I can check each time if the row should be added or not in the DataTable. Finally, I assign the DataTable to the report DataSource

Comment: I can check if a certain row should be added but the thing is, I **need** the row to be added in order to properly offset the last line which will be the one printed. I just want a way to hide the previous rows so that they don't get printed over the ones already present in the paper.

Comment: Is there a way to "print" the old rows in white, and just the last row "black", so to speak?

Comment: If I print it in white, it will also print over the older printed text. Plus, the paper isn't an ordinary bond paper, but has a design behind it so that's still a no-go if ever.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an IIF(condition,true,false) statement in your report definition on the row visibility variable.

The best way i guess is to define in your data source something of a rank column.

example :

select col1,col2,col3,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col3 DESC) AS 'rank' from table1

Then in your table or matrix, you  click on the row or/and column that you want to make the borders and text white based on a expression.

Go to the properties and dropdown on bordercolor 
choose expression and type in (based on my example query)

=IIf(rank.value <> max(rank.value),White,Black)
That will not remove the rows only make the borders white ( unvisible)

The same you can do with Font Color property.

I think this is your best shot at this issue. 
Other solution I could think of is to just hide unneccesary rows (which also replaces the visible row)

Then to move the table down by using a expression with a formula like nr of rows hidden before the actual row * height of 1 row, only I m not sure if this is applicable without programming an RDL extension..

Good Luck !

Comment: Does setting stuff to "white" make them invisible on printing? The paper isn't plain white so it will be visible if otherwise.